# Find pseudo elements in protractor

Tags: protractor, pseudo-element

I am new to protractor. I am working on clicking on a download icon which is  a pseudo element. How to get the element? please help me.

[image: html and css of the element]

[image: element to click]

Comment: by.css("a[download='MyDeals.xlsx']") try this.

Comment: Tried, but not working.it says "Failed: element not visible" exception

Comment: can put the screenshot of element

Comment: added above in the question

Comment: by.css("[ng-repeat='item in bulkImp.mydealsdownloadstatus']>a")

Comment: still not working

Comment: What is the error your facing?

Comment: looks like protractor is not clicking on the anchor element since it is not visible. We have to fetch the download icon which is not included in the dom. it is I think a pseudo property.

Comment: This should work i guess `$(" a > span.download").click()`

Answer (score 0):

Use the ng-click :

```
$('[ng-click="bulkImp.DownloadBulkExportFile(item,false)]').click();
```